# Rails - How to show attribute of parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am making an app with Rails 4.

I am trying to understand how to work with associations and to show attributes from associated models. I'm struggling to grasp the concepts.

I have a project model and a project_invitations model.

The associations are:

```
Projects has many project invitations
Project invitations belong to project
```

In my project_invitation show, I am trying to display the project attributes as well as the project creator attributes (stored in user profiles table).

I am getting stuck.

In project_invitation show, I have:

```
You're invited to participate in <%= project_invitation.project.title %>
```

I have also tried:

```
You're invited to participate in <%= @project_invitation.project.title %>
```

When I try ^^ I get this error:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

In my project table, I have an attribute called :title.

I want the project invitation show to show the name of the project to which the invitee has been invited.

What's wrong with the way I've tried to do it?

My project_invitations controller has the following (generated by scaffold):

```
class ProjectInvitationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project_invitation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /project_invitations
  # GET /project_invitations.json
  def index
    @project_invitations = ProjectInvitation.all
  end

  # GET /project_invitations/1
  # GET /project_invitations/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /project_invitations/new
  def new
    @project_invitation = ProjectInvitation.new
  end

  # GET /project_invitations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /project_invitations
  # POST /project_invitations.json
  def create
    @project_invitation = ProjectInvitation.new(project_invitation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_invitation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project_invitation, notice: 'Project invitation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project_invitation }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project_invitation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /project_invitations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /project_invitations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_invitation.update(project_invitation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project_invitation, notice: 'Project invitation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project_invitation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /project_invitations/1
  # DELETE /project_invitations/1.json
  def destroy
    @project_invitation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_invitations_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project_invitation
      @project_invitation = ProjectInvitation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_invitation_params
      if can? :create, Project,
        params[:project_invitation].permit(:comment, :expiry_date, :draft, :course_credit)
      elsif can? :read, ProjectInvitation
        params[:project_invitation].permit(:student_accepted, :sponsor_accepted)
      end
    end
end
```

The project_invitation model has:

```
class ProjectInvitation < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :project
      belongs_to :user
end
```

The project model has:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  include RoleModel

  #belongs_to :students, through: :courses, counter_cache: true

  has_many :project_questions, dependent: :destroy#, through: :projects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_questions

  has_one :sweep
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sweep

  has_one :educator_project_comment
  has_many :project_student_eois
  belongs_to :educator
  has_many :project_invitations
  has_one :video
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :video
  has_one :finalise, through: :sweep
  has_many :observations

  has_one :approval_request
  belongs_to :industry
  belongs_to :course

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :profiles, through: :industry


  mount_uploader :hero_image, AvatarUploader
  mount_uploader :link_to_video_proposal, VideoUploader
end
```

In my project_invitiatons show page, I have:

```
<div class="containerfluid">
<%= render 'static/deviselinks'%>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <h1 class="header-project" style="margin-bottom:10%">You're invited to participate in <%= @project_invitation.project.try(:title) %></h1>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:5%">

                    <div class="invitebody">
                        <%= @project_invitation.comment %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="padding:5%">
                    <div class="invitebody">
                        If you'd like to participate in this project, reply by <%= @project_invitation.expiry_date.try(:strftime, '%d %B %Y') %>
                        <br>
                        <%= render 'rsvp' %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>



        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" style="padding: 10%">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <% if @creator_profile.image.present? %>
                        <%= image_tag (@creator_profile.image.profile) %>
                    <% else %>
                        <div class="generaltext">Image TBC</div>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <%= "#{@creator_profile.title} #{@creator.first_name} #{@creator.last_name}" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <%= image_tag (@project.hero_image.thumb) %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <%= @project.title %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="formminor">
      <%= link_to 'Back', project_invitations_path %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I put 'try' before 'title' because I am having other issues saving a new invitation. I wanted to see if that was my only problem. I was expecting the next error to be of the same kind and flagging the problem with 'comment'. It jumped over that and raised an error as:

```
undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass
```

That's strange to me because I'm only asking if there is one present. Also, that code comes after the question about comment and it doesn't seem to have a problem there.

This is all a bit confusing.

Comment: What do your controllers look like? When you fire up the console, can you verify that the association methods are behaving as expected?

Comment: added my project invitations controller. There isn't anything in the project controller which refers to the project invitation table. Should there be? What should i look for in the controller?

Comment: Your instance variable will indeed be `@project_invitation`; it's being set in your controller's private `#set_project_invitation` method, which is called as a before_action at the top of your controller. How are you trying to access your show view? Are you loading the view with a project_invitation id appended, as per your controller's commented examples, e.g.: `/project_invitations/1`?

Comment: OK thank, so <%= @project_invitation.project.title %> should work? It's unclear to me whether project invitation has to be after project in this string (because project is the parent??

Comment: When i try ^^, I get this error: 
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Comment: please share your two models

Comment: @user2860931 Does the project_invitation you're viewing have a project attached to it? Try this: `<%= @project_invitation.project_id %>`. If that's nil, that means for this specific invitation, there isn't a project attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

This means the variable you're trying to access does not exist.

Ruby treats `nil` objects as `NilClass`, thus when you call a *method* on this type of object, Ruby thinks you're trying to call a method which doesn't exist. It's not the method which is the issue but the lack of variable.

---

**Associations**

Here's the code I'd expect to see:

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :invitations
end

#app/models/invitation.rb
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :project
   delegate :title, to: :project, prefix: true #-> prevents "law of demeter"
end
```

You can read about law of demeter [here](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/).

I know your model is *ProjectInvitations*; I have a rule which is to make your model names as succinct as possible - it helps with clarity throughout the app.

This will allow you to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @invitations = Invitation.all
   end

   def new
      @invitation = Invitation.new
   end

   def create
      @invitation = Invitation.new invitation_params
      @invitation.save
   end

   def show
      @invitation = Invitation.find params[:id]
   end

   private

   def invitation_params
       params.require(:invitation).permit(:user,:project)
   end
end
```

---

**Views (Fix)**

Because you haven't explained which view you're calling your erroneous variable inside, I'll have to speculate:

```
#app/views/invitations/index.html.erb
<% @invitations.each do |invitation| %>
   <%= invitation.project_title %>
<% end %>

#app/views/invitations/show.html.erb
<%= @invitation.project_title %>
```

The key is to know which view you're calling, and thus which `@variable` you have available. My guess is that you're trying to call the `@project_invitations` variable in a view where it's not defined.

---

**Model**

As an aside, you really shouldn't have that many associations in one model.

You *can* - there's no rule against it - but the problem with so much specification is that you end up creating small functionality for one single purpose.

The best systems are [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - they reuse functionality time and time again.

For example...

```
has_one :educator_project_comment
```

This could be changed to the following:

```
has_many :comments do
   def educators
      where type = "Educator"
   end
end
```

You'd then be able to have an [STI table setup](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) for `Comments`, a `type` column denoting which dependent model you're calling (in this case "Educator").

Comment: OK, I follow most of this. Thank you. What's weirding me out is that the project_invitation view page (which is the one causing the problem), is now fixed when I make the edits shown in the new bit of my question, but the next error thrown is with creator image if section. Why doesn't it have a problem with the 'comment'?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your .erb file is correct. The error shows that there's no project associated with @project_invitation. I think the problem may be in your controller code. You should assign a specific project to the new project_invitation, in the create action.

Try this code:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.first  #Here I use the first project in your database, you should change it to the project you want to associate with.
    #For example, if you are creating project invitations in projects#show view, you can use the following instead
    #@project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project_invitation = @project.project_invitations.build(project_invitation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_invitation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project_invitation, notice: 'Project invitation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project_invitation }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project_invitation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```